# How can i implement Oauth2 in SpringBoot client-server comunnication beside of Spring Oauth and external Oauth providers?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I'm looking for different way to implement Oauth2 between client and server which are developed with Spring Boot. I already tried with Spring Oauth and external providers and both ways implemented with success but they don't meet my expectations. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What expectations weren't met and why?

Comment: i would say gaining of knowledge about oauth2, i mean with external providers all is happening behind the scene, so basically all i learned was integration with external providers and some basic assumptions. Ofcourse with spring Oauth2 i get deeper touch into it, but then i started wondering if there is more "raw" approach (without annotations and any magic behind the scene..)

Answer (score 1):

All OAuth2 server provides OIDC endpoints which can be accessed using the clients and secrets provided by the sevrer. You can use Rest calls inside the code using HttpClient or Resteasy to access these endpoints. Also the URLs for endpoints that need to be accessed are based on the provider of the Oauth2 service (Auth0 or Keycloak). You can find the specification of the endoints of Oauth2 [here](https://connect2id.com/products/server/docs/api)